# Select box Onchange: autosubmit() option with php

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, html-select

So it's like I have a selectbox, with while loop as option as I want to bring out the options from database, is it possible to click on the option and link?

The while loop is like this

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result0))
{
$option .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Font_Family'].'</option>';
}
```

This is the select box

```
<select id='font' style="width:100px;" onchange="autosubmit();">
            <option value ="0">Select</option>
```

But on clicking the option I want to link it to

```
 font.php?id={id that is being pointed to}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use Javascript and create the 'autosubmit' function. A simple window.location change to the getElementById('font').value will get you started.

Comment: A select element is not a link, you'll need to use javascript, and even in javascript there are issues with click handlers on options, and you should probably bind something to the change event of the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to call the onchange.

Between the header tags, put:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function autosubmit() {
      window.location="font.php?id="+document.getElementById("font").value;
    }
  </script>
```

View the working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uwuyoz/1/

Please note, you'll have to uncomment the window.location. I simply have it 'alerting' now. But all the code is there.